# issue with hhline and cellcolor in table

Tags: tables, multirow, cline, cellcolor, hhline

I am trying to setup a table with `\hhline` and `\cellcolor`. After I got it so far, that  I don't see `\hhline`s in the colored cells I am now missing the black `\hhline`s which should separate the cells. This is how it should look like:

[image]

Here's what I have:
[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
% General document formatting
\usepackage[margin=0.7in]{geometry}
\usepackage[parfill]{parskip}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{multirow, hhline}

% Related to math
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts,amsthm}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}



\begin{document}    
    \begin{table}[!ht]  
        \centering
        \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
            \hhline{*{1}{-}}
            {\cellcolor[HTML]{C0E5C6}}Modell-Überkategorien   &\multicolumn{2}{c}{}    \\ 
            \cline{1-1}
            statisch                &\multicolumn{2}{c}{}   \\ 
            \cline{1-1}
            zufällig (Monte-Carlo)  &\multicolumn{2}{c}{}   \\ 
            \hhline{*{3}{-}}            
            \cellcolor[HTML]{E2EFD9} & \cellcolor[HTML]{E2EFD9} Kontinuirlich & \cellcolor[HTML]{E2EFD9} \\
            \hhline{>{\arrayrulecolor[HTML]{E2EFD9}}->{\arrayrulecolor{black}}->{\arrayrulecolor[HTML]{E2EFD9}}-}
            \cellcolor[HTML]{E2EFD9} & \cellcolor[HTML]{E2EFD9} Hybrid & \cellcolor[HTML]{E2EFD9}\\
            \hhline{>{\arrayrulecolor[HTML]{E2EFD9}}->{\arrayrulecolor{black}}->{\arrayrulecolor[HTML]{E2EFD9}}-} \multirow{-3}{*}{{\cellcolor[HTML]{E2EFD9}}dynamisch} 
            & \cellcolor[HTML]{E2EFD9} Diskret & \cellcolor[HTML]{E2EFD9} \multirow{-3}{*}{Raum/Zeit}  \\ 
            \hline
            \cellcolor[HTML]{E2EFD9} (Multi)-Agenten basiert &\multicolumn{2}{c}{} \\ 
            \hhline{*{1}{-}}
        \end{tabular}
        \bigskip
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

I have two missing hhlines and theres some small spaces inbetween the borders of the multirow cells. Is there a way to fix this issue?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Pleas add preamble to your code fragment. You probably have problems with poor rendering of your pdf viewer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have two MWEs: the last one cure both problems, the first does not cure the small green spaces.

**Using [hhline](https://ctan.org/pkg/hhline)**

You have forgotten to turn on `arrayrowcolor{black}` two places. In addition, the `hhline`- syntax was wrong one place. I have not found a solution for the small spaces in the horizontal borders (yet). It is the green coloured `arrayrule` under the `multirow` that overwrite the vertical line.

Not related: You load `multirow` twice.

```
\documentclass{article}
% General document formatting
\usepackage[margin=0.7in]{geometry}
\usepackage[parfill]{parskip}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{multirow, hhline}

% Related to math
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts,amsthm}
\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}

\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}
\setlength{\extrarowheight}{1pt}

\begin{document}    
    \begin{table}[!ht]  
        \centering
        \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
            \hhline{-~~}
            {\cellcolor[HTML]{C0E5C6}}Modell-Überkategorien   &\multicolumn{2}{c}{}    \\ 
            \hhline{-~~}
            statisch                &\multicolumn{2}{c}{}   \\ 
            \hhline{-~~}
            zufällig (Monte-Carlo)  &\multicolumn{2}{c}{}   \\ 
            \hhline{*{3}{-}}            
            \cellcolor[HTML]{E2EFD9} & \cellcolor[HTML]{E2EFD9} Kontinuirlich & \cellcolor[HTML]{E2EFD9} \\
            \hhline{>{\arrayrulecolor[HTML]{E2EFD9}}->{\arrayrulecolor{black}}->{\arrayrulecolor[HTML]{E2EFD9}}-}\arrayrulecolor{black}
            \cellcolor[HTML]{E2EFD9} & \cellcolor[HTML]{E2EFD9} Hybrid & \cellcolor[HTML]{E2EFD9}\\
            \hhline{>{\arrayrulecolor[HTML]{E2EFD9}}->{\arrayrulecolor{black}}->{\arrayrulecolor[HTML]
{E2EFD9}}-}\arrayrulecolor{black}
\multirow{-3}{*}{{\cellcolor[HTML]{E2EFD9}}dynamisch} 
            & \cellcolor[HTML]{E2EFD9} Diskret & \cellcolor[HTML]{E2EFD9} \multirow{-3}{*}{Raum/Zeit}  \\ 
            \hhline{|---}
            \cellcolor[HTML]{E2EFD9} (Multi)-Agenten basiert &\multicolumn{2}{c}{} \\ 
            \hhline{|-~~}
        \end{tabular}
        \bigskip
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Using [cals](https://ctan.org/pkg/cals)**

Your tabular is much easier to build using [cals](https://ctan.org/pkg/hhline).

```
\documentclass{article}
% General document formatting
\usepackage[margin=0.7in]{geometry}
\usepackage[parfill]{parskip}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{cals}

% Related to math
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts,amsthm}
\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}

\let\nc=\nullcell                                                  % Shortcuts
\let\sc=\spancontent

\definecolor{darkGreen}{HTML}{C0E5C6}
\definecolor{lightGreen}{HTML}{E2EFD9}


\begin{document}

\begin{calstable}

% Defining 3 column relativ to each other and relativ to the margins
\colwidths{{\dimexpr(\columnwidth/16*4)\relax}
            {\dimexpr(\columnwidth/16*3)\relax}
            {\dimexpr(\columnwidth/16*3)\relax}
            }
% The tabular fills 5/8 of the text area

% Set up the tabular
\makeatletter
\def\cals@framers@width{0.4pt}   % Outside frame horizontal rules
\def\cals@framecs@width{0.4pt}   % Outside frame horizontal rules, reduce
                                 % thickness if you find them too heavy
\cals@setpadding{Ag}
\cals@setcellprevdepth{Al}
\def\cals@cs@width{0.4pt}        % Inside rules, reduce if the rule is too heavy
\def\cals@rs@width{0.4pt}
\def\cals@bgcolor{}              % Define cals@bgcolor to empty

\def\green{\ifx\cals@bgcolor\empty      % Colour switch (on-off)
    \def\cals@bgcolor{darkGreen}
\else \def\cals@bgcolor{} \fi}

\def\lgreen{\ifx\cals@bgcolor\empty     % Colour switch (on-off)
    \def\cals@bgcolor{lightGreen}
\else \def\cals@bgcolor{} \fi}

\def\tb{\ifx\cals@borderT\relax     % Top border switch (off-on)
    \def\cals@borderT{0pt}
\else \let\cals@borderT\relax\fi}

\def\bb{\ifx\cals@borderB\relax     % Botton border switch (off-on)
    \def\cals@borderB{0pt}
\else \let\cals@borderB\relax\fi}

\def\rb{\ifx\cals@borderR\relax     % Right border switch (off-on)
    \def\cals@borderR{0pt}
\else \let\cals@borderR\relax\fi}

% R1 Body
\brow
    \green\alignC\cell{Modell-Überkategorien}\green
    \tb\rb\nc{lt}
    \nc{rt}\tb\rb
\erow
% R2 Body
\brow
    \cell{statisch}
    \rb\nc{l}
    \nc{r}\rb
\erow
% R3 Body
\brow
    \cell{zufällig (Monte-Carlo)}
    \rb\nc{lb}
    \nc{rb}\sc{}\rb
\erow
% R4 Body
\brow
    \lgreen\nc{lrt}
    \cell{Kontinuirlich}
    \nc{lrt}
\erow
% R5 Body
\brow
    \nc{lr}
    \cell{Hybrid}
    \nc{lr}
\erow
% R6 Body
\brow
    \nc{lrb}\sc{\vfil dynamisch}
    \cell{Diskret}
    \nc{lrb}\sc{\vfil Raum/Zeit}
\erow
% R7 Body
\brow
    \cell{(Multi)-Agenten basiert}\lgreen
    \rb\bb\nc{ltb}
    \nc{rtb}\sc{}\bb\rb
\erow
\makeatletter
\end{calstable}\par % \par needed to align the tabular

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Wow awesome. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

Small modification of first example (+1) regarding use of colors in table in the nice [Sveinung](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/494160/issue-with-hhline-and-cellcolor-in-table/494235#494235) answer (for exercise)):

```
\documentclass{article}
% General document formatting
\usepackage[margin=0.7in]{geometry}
\usepackage[parfill]{parskip}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{multirow, hhline}

% Related to math
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts,amsthm}
\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}
\definecolor{col1}{HTML}{C0E5C6}    % <---
\definecolor{col2}{HTML}{E2EFD9}    % <---

\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}
\setlength{\extrarowheight}{1pt}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[!ht]
    \centering
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
    \hhline{-~~}
\cellcolor{col1}{Modell-Überkategorien} % <---
                        &   \multicolumn{2}{c}{}    \\
    \hhline{-~~}
statisch                &   \multicolumn{2}{c}{}    \\
    \hhline{-~~}
zufällig (Monte-Carlo)  &   \multicolumn{2}{c}{}    \\
    \hhline{*{3}{-}}
\rowcolor{col2} 
                        & Kontinuirlich &           \\  % <---
    \hhline{>{\arrayrulecolor{col2}}-%
            >{\arrayrulecolor{black}}-%
            >{\arrayrulecolor{col2}}-}
    \arrayrulecolor{black}
\rowcolor{col2} 
                        & Hybrid        &           \\
    \hhline{>{\arrayrulecolor{col2}}-%
            >{\arrayrulecolor{black}}-%
            >{\arrayrulecolor{col2}}-}
    \arrayrulecolor{black}
\rowcolor{col2}
\multirow{-3}{*}{dynamisch}
                        & Diskret       & \multirow{-3}{*}{Raum/Zeit}   \\
    \hhline{|---}
\cellcolor{col2} (Multi)-Agenten basiert
                        &   \multicolumn{2}{c}{}    \\
    \hhline{|-~~}
\end{tabular}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

Result is the same as in his answer.

Comment: Thank you @Zarko. I planned to clean up my code, but now there is no need for that :).

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution with `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix`. This environment is similar to the classical `{tabular}` (of `array`) but with additional features.

- With the key `corners`, you tell `nicematrix` to take into account the empty corners (see below).
- You merge cells both vertically and horizontally with the command `\Block`.
- The key `hvlines` draws all the rules, taking into account the blocks and the corners.
- There is commands to color cells, columns and rows (in the `\CodeBefore`). The cells in the corners are not filled.

With `nicematrix`, you won't have artefacts in some PDF viewers at some level of zoom (as you can have with PDF created with `colortbl`).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}
\setlength{\extrarowheight}{1pt}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[!ht]
\centering
\begin{NiceTabular}{ccc}[corners,hvlines]
\CodeBefore
  \cellcolor[HTML]{C0E5C6}{1-1}
  \rowcolor[HTML]{E2EFD9}{4-*}
\Body
  Modell-Überkategorien \\
  statisch \\
  zufällig (Monte-Carlo)  \\
  \Block{3-1}{dynamisch} & Kontinuirlich & \Block{3-1}{Raum/Zeit} \\
                         & Hybrid        &  \\
                         & Diskret \\
  (Multi)-Agenten basiert
\end{NiceTabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

You need several compilations (because `nicematrix` uses PGF/Tikz nodes under the hood).

[image: Ouput of the above code]