# Activity Schedule Table

Tags: tables, cellcolor

I would like help getting ahead and being able to make this activity schedule table. I'm used to making tables simpler but so colorful I don't know. So please, I would appreciate your help.

Thank you very much.

[image]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a `just-do-it-for-me` question (-1).

Comment: What you try so far? At least you should provide the skeleton of table in form of MWE (Minimal Working Example, a small self contained document). Coloring of cells is simple. In preamble you need to add `\usepackage[table]{xcolor}` and than in cells to be colored insert `\cellcolor{<desired color>}`.

Comment: @down-voters: **Please don't downvote below a score of -1, even if the question in its current form needs some improvement. A score of -1 is enough to show that the question needs work, anything below that is of no use.** Also, if you downvote or vote to close, please leave a comment explaining why you did so, but wait at least 24 hours after asking the OP for improvements to the question before voting to close.

Comment: @Raaja before voting to close give a new or low rep user a chance to add more information to a not so good question. You are voting to close absolutly too fast! See for a good reaction the comment of user zarko!

Comment: @Mensch imo the OP is not a new user to this site. The OP has been in this site for a long time now.

Comment: Probably you could also use the pgfgantt package for your table.

Comment: @Raaja Well, it is a low rep user and the last question was some time ago. It is possible this OP forget the handling here in such a long time away from here. This is a friendly page and vote to close after one minute is not friendly, sorry.

Comment: @Mensch ok no problems.

Comment: This is just an ordinary table with some coloured cells. If all the vertical and horizontal line s important for you, you should use the package [cals](https://ctan.org/pkg/cals), because `tabular` with rules and colours have a problem with disappearing rules (colour overlays the rules).

Comment: Please read the [introductory material](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) for this site. When you post a question, you are expected to provide a ["Minimal Working Example" (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that starts with `\documentclass`, includes all relevant `\usepackage` commands, ends with `\end{document}` and compiles without errors, even if it does not produce your desired output. Users tend to provide better assistance when the poster makes a greater effort.

Comment: @Sveinung This table is just an example of a result you would like the tavela to look like. However, I try to adapt the code you made to what I need to get. I have never worked with this cals package. So my difficulty is inserting and removing columns. I'm trying to make in 2015 only 1 column (quarter 3), in 2016, 3 columns (quarter 1, quarter 2, quarter 3), in 2017, 3 columns (quarter 1, quarter 2, quarter 3), in 2018, 3 columns (quarter 1, quarter 2, quarter 3) and finally in 2019, 2 columns (quarter 1, quarter 2).

Comment: @Sveinung I have an example I could do in Excel, although not the same as in Latex. I replaced the example attached earlier with the new result I was able to do in Excel. But I wish I could do it in Latex using cals package.

Comment: The excel sheet is easy to reproduce using my last example.

Comment: @Sveinung The problem is, I can't make this table in Latex by any means using the cals package like you did so masterfully. Although I tried in every way.

Comment: Yes, you can (is just a matter of training). Compare my code and see what I have changes.

Comment: @Sveinung OK! I will follow your recommendation.

Answer (score 6):

Here are three `calstable`s you can continue to work on. Look at the definition of columns which distributes them over the whole text width. Next check the spanning. A span needs to cover at least two cells, and the letters tell which place in the span a cell has - t(top) b(bottom) l(left) and r(right). So a cell in a span with the letters `ltb` is the cell that starts a span in a horizontal, one row span. The last cell in such span is `\nc{rtb}` (study [this document](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/cals/notes.pdf)):

Example 2:

1. I added six new column to the right of the last column in example 1. The divisor for calculating the column width, had to be increased from 74 to 78 and the column widths fine tuned to cover all the new columns.
2. I "removed" a column from 2015 (1. semester) just by removing the spanning
3. Spanning for row 1 was increased from six to twelve cells
4. Spanning was added in row 2 for 2017, 2018, 2019 and 2020
5. Copied semesters from 2016 to 217, 2018, 2019 and 2020
6. Cleaned up the last row increased spanning, mowed the commands for switching off rules (borders) to the last column

**example 1**

[image]

```
\documentclass[DIV=13, landscape]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{cals, ragged2e, lmodern}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage[sgvnames]{xcolor}


\let\nc=\nullcell                         % Shorthands
\let\sc=\spancontent


\begin{document}

%\begin{landscape}
\RaggedRight
\captionaboveof{table}{Activity Schedule}\medskip
\label{table-1}
\begin{calstable}[c]
% Defining column relative to each other and relative to the margins
\colwidths{{\dimexpr(\columnwidth)/72*3\relax}
            {\dimexpr(\columnwidth)/72*33\relax}
            {\dimexpr(\columnwidth)/36*3\relax}
            {\dimexpr(\columnwidth)/36*3\relax}
            {\dimexpr(\columnwidth)/36*3\relax}
            {\dimexpr(\columnwidth)/36*3\relax}
            {\dimexpr(\columnwidth)/36*3\relax}
            {\dimexpr(\columnwidth)/36*3\relax}
            }
% The tabular fills the text area if sum of all columns is 72 

% Set up the tabular
\makeatletter
\def\cals@framers@width{0.4pt}   % Outside frame rules, reduce if the rule is too heavy
\def\cals@framecs@width{0.4pt}
\def\cals@bodyrs@width{0.4pt}
\def\cals@cs@width{0.4pt}             % Inside rules, reduce if the rule is too heavy
\def\cals@rs@width{0.4pt}
\def\cals@bgcolor{}
\setlength{\cals@paddingL}{3pt}
\setlength{\cals@paddingR}{3pt}
\def\cals@AtBeginCell{\vfil}

\def\cred{\ifx\cals@bgcolor\empty
\def\cals@bgcolor{red!70}
\else\def\cals@bgcolor{} \fi}

\def\cblue{\ifx\cals@bgcolor\empty
\def\cals@bgcolor{blue!75}
\else\def\cals@bgcolor{} \fi}

\def\tb{\ifx\cals@borderT\relax     % Top border switch (off-on)
    \def\cals@borderT{0pt}
\else\let\cals@borderT\relax\fi}

\def\bb{\ifx\cals@borderB\relax     % Bottom border switch (off-on)
    \def\cals@borderB{0pt}
\else\let\cals@borderB\relax\fi}

\def\rb{\ifx\cals@borderR\relax     % Right border switch (off-on)
    \def\cals@borderR{0pt}
\else\let\cals@borderR\relax\fi}

\def\lb{\ifx\cals@borderL\relax     % Left border switch (off-on)
    \def\cals@borderL{0pt}
\else\let\cals@borderL\relax\fi}


% R1
\thead{\bfseries
\brow
    \nc{lt}
    \nc{rt}
    \nc{ltb}
    \nc{tb}
    \nc{tb}
    \nc{tb}
    \nc{tb}
    \nc{rtb}\alignC\sc{TRIMESTRES}
\erow
\brow
    \nc{lb}
    \nc{rb}\sc{}
    \nc{ltb}
    \nc{rtb}\sc{2015}
    \nc{ltb}
    \nc{rtb}\sc{2016}
    \nc{ltb}
    \nc{rtb}\sc{2017}
\erow
% R3 Head
\brow
    \nc{ltb}
    \nc{rtb}\sc{Ativadades}
    \cell{1\textsuperscript{o}}
    \cell{2\textsuperscript{o}}
    \cell{3\textsuperscript{o}}
    \cell{4\textsuperscript{o}}
    \cell{5\textsuperscript{o}}
    \cell{6\textsuperscript{o}}
\erow
}  % Heading end
\mdseries
%\tfoot{%
%   \lastrule\nointerlineskip%
%   \textit{\strut Activity Schedule continues on next page%
%   }%
%   \par%
%   }
% R4 Body
\brow
    \cell{\bfseries 1}
    \alignL\cell{\vfil Pesquisa Bibliográfica}
    \cblue\cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}\cblue
    \cred\cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}\cred
\erow
% R4 Body
\brow
\brow
    \alignC\cell{\bfseries 2}
    \alignL\cell{}
    \cblue\cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}\cblue
    \cred\cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}\cred
\erow
% R5 Body
\brow
    \alignC\cell{\bfseries 3}
    \alignL\cell{}
    \cblue\cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}\cblue
    \cred\cell{}
    \cell{}\cred
    \cell{}
\erow
% R6 Body
\brow
    \alignC\cell{\bfseries 4}
    \alignL\cell{}
    \cblue\cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}\cblue
    \cred\cell{}
    \cell{}\cred
    \cell{}
\erow
% R7 Body
\brow
    \alignC\cell{\bfseries 5}
    \alignL\cell{}
    \cblue\cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}\cblue
    \cred\cell{}\cred
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
\erow
% R8 Body
\brow
    \alignC\cell{\bfseries 6}
    \alignL\cell{}
    \cblue\cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}\cblue
    \cred\cell{}
    \cell{}\cred
    \cell{}
\erow
% R9 Body
\brow
    \alignC\cell{\bfseries 7}
    \alignL\cell{}
    \cblue\cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}\cblue
    \cred\cell{}
    \cell{}\cred
    \cell{}
\erow
% R10 Body
\brow
    \alignC\cell{\bfseries 8}
    \alignL\cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cblue\cell{}\cblue
    \cred\cell{}\cred
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
\erow
% R11 Body
\brow
    \alignC\cell{\bfseries 9}
    \alignL\cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cred\cell{}
    \cell{}\cred
    \cell{}
\erow
% R12 Body
\brow
    \alignC\cell{\bfseries 10}
    \alignL\cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cred\cell{}
    \cell{}\cred
    \cell{}
\erow
% R14 Body
\brow
    \alignC\cell{\bfseries 11}
    \alignL\cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cred\cell{}
    \cell{}\cred
\erow
% R15 Body
\brow
    \alignC\cell{\bfseries 12}
    \alignL\cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cred\cell{}
    \cell{}\cred
\erow
% R16 Body
\brow
    \alignC\cell{\bfseries 13}
    \alignL\cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cred\cell{}
    \cell{}\cred
\erow
% R17 Body
\brow
    \alignC\cell{\bfseries 14}
    \alignL\cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cred\cell{}
    \cell{}\cred
\erow
% R18 Body 15
\brow
    \alignC\cell{\bfseries 15}
    \alignL\cell{Producão de dios artigos cientifigos na base lSl}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cred\cell{}
    \cell{}\cred\bb\lb\rb
\erow
% R19 Footer
\brow
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
\erow
% R20 Footer
\brow
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cblue\cell{}\cblue
    \nc{ltb}
    \nc{rtb}\alignL\sc{\footnotesize atividades realizadas}
    \cred\cell{}\cred
    \nc{ltb}
    \nc{rtb}\alignL\sc{\footnotesize atividades previstas}\bb\lb\rb
\erow
\makeatletter
\end{calstable}\par % \par to align the tabular
%\end{landscape}

\end{document}
```

**example 2**

[image]

```
\documentclass[DIV=13, landscape]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{cals, ragged2e, lmodern}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage[sgvnames]{xcolor}

\let\nc=\nullcell                                                  % Shortcuts
\let\sc=\spancontent

\begin{document}

%\begin{landscape}
\RaggedRight\small
\captionaboveof{table}{Activity Schedule}\medskip
\label{table-1}
\begin{calstable}[c]
% Defining column relative to each other and relative to the margins
\colwidths{{\dimexpr(\columnwidth)/78*3\relax}
            {\dimexpr(\columnwidth)/78*27\relax}
            {\dimexpr(\columnwidth)/78*4\relax}
            {\dimexpr(\columnwidth)/78*4\relax}
            {\dimexpr(\columnwidth)/78*4\relax}
            {\dimexpr(\columnwidth)/78*4\relax}
            {\dimexpr(\columnwidth)/78*4\relax}
            {\dimexpr(\columnwidth)/78*4\relax}
            {\dimexpr(\columnwidth)/78*4\relax}
            {\dimexpr(\columnwidth)/78*4\relax}
            {\dimexpr(\columnwidth)/78*4\relax}
            {\dimexpr(\columnwidth)/78*4\relax}
            {\dimexpr(\columnwidth)/78*4\relax}
            {\dimexpr(\columnwidth)/78*4\relax}
            }
% The tabular fills the text area if sum of all columns is 78 

% Set up the tabular
\makeatletter
\def\cals@framers@width{0.4pt}   % Outside frame rules, reduce if the rule is too heavy
\def\cals@framecs@width{0.4pt}
\def\cals@bodyrs@width{0.4pt}
\def\cals@cs@width{0.4pt}             % Inside rules, reduce if the rule is too heavy
\def\cals@rs@width{0.4pt}
\def\cals@bgcolor{}
\setlength{\cals@paddingL}{3pt}
\setlength{\cals@paddingR}{3pt}
\def\cals@AtBeginCell{\vfil}

\def\cred{\ifx\cals@bgcolor\empty
\def\cals@bgcolor{red!70}
\else\def\cals@bgcolor{} \fi}

\def\cblue{\ifx\cals@bgcolor\empty
\def\cals@bgcolor{blue!75}
\else\def\cals@bgcolor{} \fi}

\def\tb{\ifx\cals@borderT\relax     % Top border switch (off-on)
    \def\cals@borderT{0pt}
\else\let\cals@borderT\relax\fi}

\def\bb{\ifx\cals@borderB\relax     % Bottom border switch (off-on)
    \def\cals@borderB{0pt}
\else\let\cals@borderB\relax\fi}

\def\rb{\ifx\cals@borderR\relax     % Right border switch (off-on)
    \def\cals@borderR{0pt}
\else\let\cals@borderR\relax\fi}

\def\lb{\ifx\cals@borderL\relax     % Left border switch (off-on)
    \def\cals@borderL{0pt}
\else\let\cals@borderL\relax\fi}


% R1
\thead{\bfseries
\brow
    \nc{lt}
    \nc{rt}
    \nc{ltb}
    \nc{tb}
    \nc{tb}
    \nc{tb}
    \nc{tb}
    \nc{tb}
    \nc{tb}
    \nc{tb}
    \nc{tb}
    \nc{tb}
    \nc{tb}
    \nc{rtb}\alignC\sc{TRIMESTRES}
\erow
\brow
    \nc{lb}
    \nc{rb}\sc{}
    \alignC\cell{2015}
    \nc{ltb}
    \nc{tb}
    \nc{rtb}\sc{2016}
    \nc{ltb}
    \nc{tb}
    \nc{rtb}\sc{2017}
    \nc{ltb}
    \nc{tb}
    \nc{rtb}\sc{2018}
    \nc{ltb}
    \nc{rtb}\sc{2019}
\erow
% R3 Head
\brow
    \nc{ltb}
    \nc{rtb}\sc{Ativadades}
    \cell{3\textsuperscript{o}}
    \cell{1\textsuperscript{o}}
    \cell{2\textsuperscript{o}}
    \cell{3\textsuperscript{o}}
    \cell{1\textsuperscript{o}}
    \cell{2\textsuperscript{o}}
    \cell{3\textsuperscript{o}}
    \cell{1\textsuperscript{o}}
    \cell{2\textsuperscript{o}}
    \cell{3\textsuperscript{o}}
    \cell{1\textsuperscript{o}}
    \cell{2\textsuperscript{o}}
\erow
}  % Heading end
\mdseries
%\tfoot{%
%   \lastrule\nointerlineskip%
%   \textit{\strut Activity Schedule continues on next page%
%   }%
%   \par%
%   }
% R4 Body
\brow
    \cell{\bfseries 1}
    \alignL\cell{\vfil Pesquisa Bibliográfica}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
\erow
% R4 Body
\brow
\brow
    \alignC\cell{\bfseries 2}
    \alignL\cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
\erow
% R5 Body
\brow
    \alignC\cell{\bfseries 3}
    \alignL\cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
\erow
% R6 Body
\brow
    \alignC\cell{\bfseries 4}
    \alignL\cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
\erow
% R7 Body
\brow
    \alignC\cell{\bfseries 5}
    \alignL\cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
\erow
% R8 Body
\brow
    \alignC\cell{\bfseries 6}
    \alignL\cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
\erow
% R9 Body
\brow
    \alignC\cell{\bfseries 7}
    \alignL\cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
\erow
% R10 Body
\brow
    \alignC\cell{\bfseries 8}
    \alignL\cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
\erow
% R11 Body
\brow
    \alignC\cell{\bfseries 9}
    \alignL\cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
\erow
% R12 Body
\brow
    \alignC\cell{\bfseries 10}
    \alignL\cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
\erow
% R14 Body
\brow
    \alignC\cell{\bfseries 11}
    \alignL\cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
\erow
% R15 Body
\brow
    \alignC\cell{\bfseries 12}
    \alignL\cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
\erow
% R16 Body
\brow
    \alignC\cell{\bfseries 13}
    \alignL\cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
\erow
% R17 Body
\brow
    \alignC\cell{\bfseries 14}
    \alignL\cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
\erow
% R18 Body 15
\brow
    \alignC\cell{\bfseries 15}
    \alignL\cell{Producão de dios artigos cientifigos na base lSl}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}\bb\lb\rb
\erow
% R19 Footer
\brow
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
\erow
% R20 Footer
\brow
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cblue\cell{}\cblue
    \nc{ltb}
    \nc{tb}
    \nc{rtb}\alignL\sc{\footnotesize atividades realizadas}
    \cell{}
    \cred\cell{}\cred
    \nc{ltb}
    \nc{tb}
    \nc{rtb}\alignL\sc{\footnotesize atividades previstas}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}\bb\lb\rb
\erow
\makeatletter
\end{calstable}\par % \par to align the tabular
%\end{landscape}

\end{document}
```

**example 3**

[image]

```
\documentclass[DIV=13, landscape]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{cals, ragged2e, lmodern}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage[sgvnames]{xcolor}


\let\nc=\nullcell                                                  % Shortcuts
\let\sc=\spancontent


\begin{document}

%\begin{landscape}
\RaggedRight\small
\captionaboveof{table}{Activity Schedule}\medskip
\label{table-1}
\begin{calstable}[c]
% Defining column relative to each other and relative to the margins
\colwidths{{\dimexpr(\columnwidth)/78*3\relax}
            {\dimexpr(\columnwidth)/78*27\relax}
            {\dimexpr(\columnwidth)/78*4\relax}
            {\dimexpr(\columnwidth)/78*4\relax}
            {\dimexpr(\columnwidth)/78*4\relax}
            {\dimexpr(\columnwidth)/78*4\relax}
            {\dimexpr(\columnwidth)/78*4\relax}
            {\dimexpr(\columnwidth)/78*4\relax}
            {\dimexpr(\columnwidth)/78*4\relax}
            {\dimexpr(\columnwidth)/78*4\relax}
            {\dimexpr(\columnwidth)/78*4\relax}
            {\dimexpr(\columnwidth)/78*4\relax}
            {\dimexpr(\columnwidth)/78*4\relax}
            {\dimexpr(\columnwidth)/78*4\relax}
            }
% The tabular fills the text area if sum of all columns is 78 

% Set up the tabular
\makeatletter
\def\cals@framers@width{0.4pt}   % Outside frame rules, reduce if the rule is too heavy
\def\cals@framecs@width{0.4pt}
\def\cals@bodyrs@width{0.4pt}
\def\cals@cs@width{0.4pt}             % Inside rules, reduce if the rule is too heavy
\def\cals@rs@width{0.4pt}
\def\cals@bgcolor{}
\setlength{\cals@paddingL}{3pt}
\setlength{\cals@paddingR}{3pt}
\def\cals@AtBeginCell{\vfil}

\def\cred{\ifx\cals@bgcolor\empty
\def\cals@bgcolor{red!70}
\else\def\cals@bgcolor{} \fi}

\def\cblue{\ifx\cals@bgcolor\empty
\def\cals@bgcolor{blue!75}
\else\def\cals@bgcolor{} \fi}

\def\tb{\ifx\cals@borderT\relax     % Top border switch (off-on)
    \def\cals@borderT{0pt}
\else\let\cals@borderT\relax\fi}

\def\bb{\ifx\cals@borderB\relax     % Bottom border switch (off-on)
    \def\cals@borderB{0pt}
\else\let\cals@borderB\relax\fi}

\def\rb{\ifx\cals@borderR\relax     % Right border switch (off-on)
    \def\cals@borderR{0pt}
\else\let\cals@borderR\relax\fi}

\def\lb{\ifx\cals@borderL\relax     % Left border switch (off-on)
    \def\cals@borderL{0pt}
\else\let\cals@borderL\relax\fi}


% R1
\thead{\bfseries
\brow
    \nc{lt}
    \nc{rt}
    \nc{ltb}
    \nc{tb}
    \nc{tb}
    \nc{tb}
    \nc{tb}
    \nc{tb}
    \nc{tb}
    \nc{tb}
    \nc{tb}
    \nc{tb}
    \nc{tb}
    \nc{rtb}\alignC\sc{TRIMESTRES}
\erow
\brow
    \nc{lb}
    \nc{rb}\sc{}
    \alignC\cell{2016}
    \nc{ltb}
    \nc{tb}
    \nc{rtb}\sc{2017}
    \nc{ltb}
    \nc{tb}
    \nc{rtb}\sc{2018}
    \nc{ltb}
    \nc{tb}
    \nc{rtb}\sc{2019}
    \nc{ltb}
    \nc{rtb}\sc{2020}
\erow
% R3 Head
\brow
    \nc{ltb}
    \nc{rtb}\sc{Ativadades}
    \cell{3\textsuperscript{o}}
    \cell{1\textsuperscript{o}}
    \cell{2\textsuperscript{o}}
    \cell{3\textsuperscript{o}}
    \cell{1\textsuperscript{o}}
    \cell{2\textsuperscript{o}}
    \cell{3\textsuperscript{o}}
    \cell{1\textsuperscript{o}}
    \cell{2\textsuperscript{o}}
    \cell{3\textsuperscript{o}}
    \cell{1\textsuperscript{o}}
    \cell{2\textsuperscript{o}}
\erow
}  % Heading end
\mdseries
%\tfoot{%
%   \lastrule\nointerlineskip%
%   \textit{\strut Activity Schedule continues on next page%
%   }%
%   \par%
%   }
% R4 Body
\brow
    \cell{\bfseries 1}
    \alignL\cell{\vfil Disiplinas}
    \cblue\cell{}\cblue
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
\erow
% R4 Body
\brow
\brow
    \alignC\cell{\bfseries 2}
    \alignL\cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cblue\cell{}\cblue
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
\erow
% R5 Body
\brow
    \alignC\cell{\bfseries 3}
    \alignL\cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cblue\cell{}
    \cell{}\cblue
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
\erow
% R6 Body
\brow
    \alignC\cell{\bfseries 4}
    \alignL\cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cblue\cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}\cblue
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
\erow
% R7 Body
\brow
    \alignC\cell{\bfseries 5}
    \alignL\cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cblue\cell{}\cblue
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
\erow
% R8 Body
\brow
    \alignC\cell{\bfseries 6}
    \alignL\cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cblue\cell{}
    \cell{}\cblue
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
\erow
% R9 Body
\brow
    \alignC\cell{\bfseries 7}
    \alignL\cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cblue\cell{}
    \cell{}\cblue
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
\erow
% R10 Body
\brow
    \alignC\cell{\bfseries 8}
    \alignL\cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cblue\cell{}\cblue
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
\erow
% R11 Body
\brow
    \alignC\cell{\bfseries 9}
    \alignL\cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cred\cell{}\cred
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
\erow
% R12 Body
\brow
    \alignC\cell{\bfseries 10}
    \alignL\cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cred\cell{}
    \cell{}\cred
    \cell{}
\erow
% R18 Body 15
\brow
    \alignC\cell{\bfseries 11}
    \alignL\cell{Versão Final da Tese e sua Apresentcão}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cred\cell{}\cred\bb\lb\rb
\erow
% R19 Footer
\brow
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
\erow
% R20 Footer
\brow
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cblue\cell{}\cblue
    \nc{ltb}
    \nc{tb}
    \nc{rtb}\alignL\sc{\footnotesize Atividades Realizadas}
    \cell{}
    \cred\cell{}\cred
    \nc{ltb}
    \nc{tb}
    \nc{rtb}\alignL\sc{\footnotesize Atividades Previstas}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}\bb\lb\rb
\erow
\makeatletter
\end{calstable}\par % \par to align the tabular
%\end{landscape}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

sine you are struggling with `calstable` I also typeset your activity schedule using [tabularx](https://ctan.org/pkg/tabularx). However, as you will see, the rules through colourised cells is not satisfying if you view the tabular in PDF-viewers. The rules partly disappear, because they are overlaid by the cell colour. On a printout, they may come out OK.

It is possible to partly overcome this problem by using [hhline](https://ctan.org/pkg/hhline), see the hhline-manual and [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/494235/9632).

Here is an MWE:

[image]

```
\documentclass[DIV=13, landscape]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tabularx, ragged2e, lmodern, bigstrut}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage[sgvnames, table]{xcolor}
\setlength{\extrarowheight}{2pt}
\newcommand{\blue}{\cellcolor{blue!75}}
\newcommand{\red}{\cellcolor{red!75}}
\begin{document}

\RaggedRight\small

\captionaboveof{table}{Activity Schedule}\medskip
\label{table-1}
\noindent\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|>{\bfseries}l|l|*{11}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X|}>{\centering\arraybackslash}X<{\bigstrut}|}
\hline
\multicolumn{2}{|l|}{}&\multicolumn{12}{c|}{\bfseries TRIMESTRES\bigstrut}\\
\cline{3-14}
\multicolumn{2}{|l|}{}&\bfseries 2016&\multicolumn{3}{c|}{\bfseries 2017}&\multicolumn{3}{c|}{\bfseries 2018}&\multicolumn{3}{c|}{\bfseries 2019}&\multicolumn{2}{c|}{\bfseries 2020\bigstrut}\\
\hline
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\bfseries Ativadades}&\bfseries1\textsuperscript{o}&\bfseries1\textsuperscript{o}&\bfseries2\textsuperscript{o}&\bfseries3\textsuperscript{o}&\bfseries1\textsuperscript{o}&\bfseries2\textsuperscript{o}&\bfseries3\textsuperscript{o}&\bfseries1\textsuperscript{o}&\bfseries2\textsuperscript{o}&\bfseries3\textsuperscript{o}&\bfseries1\textsuperscript{o}&\bfseries2\textsuperscript{o}\\
\hline
1&Disiplinas&\blue&&&&&&&&&&&\\
\hline
2&&&\blue&&&&&&&&&&\\
\hline
3&&&&\blue&\blue&&&&&&&&\\
\hline
4&&&&&\blue&\blue&\blue&&&&&&\\
\hline
5&&&&&&\blue&&&&&&&\\
\hline
6&&&&&&&\blue&\blue&&&&&\\
\hline
7&&&&&&&&&\blue&\blue&&&\\
\hline
8&&&&&&&&&&\blue&&&\\
\hline
9&&&&&&&&&&&\red&&\\
\hline
10&&&&&&&&&&&\red&\red&\\
\hline
11&Versão Final da Tese e sua Apresentcão&&&&&&&&&&&&\red\\
\hline
\multicolumn{14}{l}{}\\[-1.5ex]
\multicolumn{4}{l}{}&\multicolumn{1}{l}{\blue}&\multicolumn{3}{l}{\footnotesize Atividades Realizadas}&\multicolumn{1}{l}{\red}&\multicolumn{4}{l}{\footnotesize Atividades Previstas}\\
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```