# Color cell incomplete in coloured columns LaTeX and hhline details trouble

Tags: tables, color, multicolumn, makecell, hhline

I have a problem with my table in LaTeX. A few of cells doesn't fill well.
I used the package "makecell" to do multirow and define new types of columns instead colortbl package (because I read that those packages can have a conflict), but I don't know why is this happening. Also, I used hhline to do lines suitable to my table and I used a macro to change the color of line in each column(Btw, I have to deny the shorthands in the Spanish babel package to the macro works), but I still get the intersections in white.
Finally I modified the thick of the edges lines but it doesn´t work in all. Anyone could give me a suggestion, please? Thanks. Below is my code.

PD. I tried with "tabularx" and "tabulary" but it doesn't work for me.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish,es-noshorthands]{babel} %es-noshorthands sirve para que el cambio de color en hhline sea efectivo
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}

\usepackage[table,svgnames,x11names]{xcolor}
\usepackage{hhline}
\usepackage{multirow,makecell,array}
\usepackage{diagbox}

\usepackage{tabulary}
\usepackage{adjustbox} 
\usepackage{anyfontsize}

\begin{document}
\newcolumntype{g}{>{\columncolor{LightSteelBlue}}c}
\newcolumntype{h}{>{\columncolor{Gainsboro}}c}
\newcolumntype{k}{>{\columncolor{Azure3}}c}

\begin{table}
\scriptsize
\centering
\begin{adjustbox}{max width=\textwidth}
%!{\vrule width1.2pt} modifica el ancho de linea vertical divisoria en la tabla, usar en vez de \hline
% \Xhline{1.2pt} modifica el ancho de linea horizontal divisoria en la tabla, usar en vez de solo |

\begin{tabular}{!{\vrule width1.2pt}g!{\vrule width1.2pt}h!{\vrule width1.2pt}k!{\vrule width1.2pt}k!{\vrule width1.2pt}}

%\hhline{>{\arrayrulecolor{LightSteelBlue}}->{\arrayrulecolor{black}}---} %hace una linea del color de la columna 1 y luego la cambia a color negro. Aplicar solo cuando tienes columnas de colores y hay problemas
%con el multirenglón. Si tu color de tabla es blanco con \cline{-} (linea parcial) basta.

\Xhline{1.2pt} %\hline 
\multicolumn{4}{|c|}{{\textsc{Características y parámetros...}}} \\ 

\Xhline{1.2pt} %\hline 
\multicolumn{2}{|g|}{\diagbox[innerwidth=7.5cm]{\textbf{Ítem}}{\textbf{Modelo}}} & \textbf{Modelo1} & \textbf{Modelo2} \\ 

\Xhline{1.2pt} %\hline 
 & \textbf{Material de máquina} & \multicolumn{2}{|h|}{Estructuras de aluminio} \\ 
\hhline{|>{\arrayrulecolor{LightSteelBlue}}-|>{\arrayrulecolor{black}}-|-|-|}  %\cline{2-4}               

 & \textbf{Láser} & \multicolumn{2}{|h|}{Generador de láser: Fibra óptica} \\ %\cline{2-4}

\hhline{|>{\arrayrulecolor{LightSteelBlue}}-|>{\arrayrulecolor{black}}-|-|-}  %\cline{2-4}
 & \textbf{Potencia de salida} & $\geq 20W$ & $\geq 30W$ \\ 

\hhline{|>{\arrayrulecolor{LightSteelBlue}}-|>{\arrayrulecolor{black}}-|-|-}  %\cline{2-4}
 & \textbf{Longitud de onda} & \multicolumn{2}{|h|}{$1064nm$} \\ 

\hhline{|>{\arrayrulecolor{LightSteelBlue}}-|>{\arrayrulecolor{black}}-|-|-}  %\cline{2-4}
 & \textbf{Lentes} & \multicolumn{2}{|h|}{\cellcolor{Gainsboro}\makecell{Sistema de escaneo de alta precisión\\2 dimensiones}} \\ 

\hhline{|>{\arrayrulecolor{LightSteelBlue}}-|>{\arrayrulecolor{black}}-|-|-}  %\cline{2-4}
 & \textbf{Velocidad de marcado} & \multicolumn{2}{|h|}{$<8000mm/s$} \\ 

\hhline{|>{\arrayrulecolor{LightSteelBlue}}-|>{\arrayrulecolor{black}}-|-|-}  %\cline{2-4} 
 &  & \multicolumn{2}{|h|}{Pantalla* integrada} \\ 
 
% 
 & \multirowcell{-2}{\textbf{Sistema de control principal}} & \multicolumn{2}{|h|}{Controlador táctil externo 10.4''} \\ 

\hhline{>{\arrayrulecolor{LightSteelBlue}}->{\arrayrulecolor{black}}---} %\cline{2-4}
\multirowcell{-8}{Características\\máquina\\láser} & \textbf{Sistema de enfriamiento} & \multicolumn{2}{|h|}{\cellcolor{Gainsboro} \makecell{Sistema de enfriamiento\\mediante agua o aire}} \\ 
%------------------------------------------------------------------------
\Xhline{1.2pt} %\hline
 & \cellcolor{Gainsboro} \makecell{\textbf{Aumento de enfoque}\\ \textbf{lentes (zoom)}} & \multicolumn{2}{|h|}{190mm en doble enfoque con luz roja} \\ 

\hhline{>{\arrayrulecolor{LightSteelBlue}}->{\arrayrulecolor{black}}---} %\cline{2-4}
 & \textbf{Tipo de fuente de marcado} & \multicolumn{2}{|h|}{\cellcolor{Gainsboro} \makecell{Marcado elegible entre gráficos vectoriales\\o mapas de bits}} \\ 

\hhline{>{\arrayrulecolor{LightSteelBlue}}->{\arrayrulecolor{black}}---} %\cline{2-4}
 & \textbf{Ancho de línea mínimo} & \multicolumn{2}{|h|}{$0.012mm$} \\ 

\hhline{>{\arrayrulecolor{LightSteelBlue}}->{\arrayrulecolor{black}}---} %\cline{2-4}
 & \textbf{Precisión de repetibilidad} & \multicolumn{2}{|h|}{0.003mm} \\ 

\hhline{>{\arrayrulecolor{LightSteelBlue}}->{\arrayrulecolor{black}}---} %\cline{2-4}
 & \textbf{Área de trabajo} & \multicolumn{2}{|h|}{$110mm x 110mm$} \\ 

\hhline{>{\arrayrulecolor{LightSteelBlue}}->{\arrayrulecolor{black}}---} %\cline{2-4}
 & \textbf{Posicionamiento} & \multicolumn{2}{|h|}{Luz roja posiciona, doble luz roja enfoca} \\ 

\hhline{>{\arrayrulecolor{LightSteelBlue}}->{\arrayrulecolor{black}}---} %\cline{2-4}
 & \textbf{Línea de marcado} & \multicolumn{2}{|h|}{Sin límite el área de trabajo} \\ 

\hhline{>{\arrayrulecolor{LightSteelBlue}}->{\arrayrulecolor{black}}---} %\cline{2-4} 
\multirowcell{-8}{Parámetros\\de marcado\\láser} & \textbf{Velocidad} & \multicolumn{2}{|h|}{$0-200m/min$} \\ 
%-----------------------------------------------------------------
\Xhline{1.2pt} %\hline
 & \textbf{Suministro de energía} & \multicolumn{2}{|h|}{$220V$} \\ 
%\cline{2-4}
\hhline{>{\arrayrulecolor{LightSteelBlue}}->{\arrayrulecolor{black}}---}
\multirowcell{-2}{Otros} & \textbf{Consumo de potencia} & \multicolumn{2}{|h|}{$600W$} \\ 
\Xhline{1.2pt} %\hline
\end{tabular} 
\end{adjustbox}
\end{table}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/494160/issue-with-hhline-and-cellcolor-in-table

Comment: Probably you could make use of `NiceTabular` from the `nicematrix` package.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is what you can do with the environment `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix`.

- You can merge cells both horizontally and vertically with the command `\Block`.
- The key `hvlines` draws all the rules except in the blocks. Of course, these rules have all a width (thickness) equal to `\arrayrulewidth`. That's why I have drawn the heavy rules after.
- `nicematrix` creates PGF/Tikz nodes under the array. It's possible to use these nodes with Tikz. That's what I have done to draw the heavy rules.
- `nicematrix` provides a built-in command `\diagbox`

The code:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\usepackage[left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[svgnames,x11names]{xcolor}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\centering


\begin{NiceTabular}{wc{2cm}>{\bfseries}ccc}[hvlines,cell-space-limits = 4pt]
\CodeBefore
  \columncolor{LightSteelBlue}{1}
  \rectanglecolor{Gainsboro}{3-2}{-}
  \rowcolor{white}{1}
  \rectanglecolor{LightSteelBlue}{2-1}{2-2}
  \rectanglecolor{Azure3}{2-3}{2-4}
  \rectanglecolor{Azure3}{5-3}{5-4}
\Body
  \Block{1-4}{\textsc{Características y parámetros...}} & & & \\ 
  \Block{1-2}{\diagbox{\strut Ítem}{\strut Modelo}} & & \makebox[3.5cm][c]{\textbf{Modelo1}} &
  \makebox[3.5cm][c]{\textbf{Modelo2}} \\ 
  \Block{9-1}{Características\\máquina\\láser}
   & Material de máquina & \Block{1-2}{Estructuras de aluminio} \\ 
   & Láser & \Block{1-2}{Generador de láser: Fibra óptica} \\
   & Potencia de salida & $\geq 20$ W & $\geq 30$ W \\ 
   & Longitud de onda & \Block{1-2}{$1064$ nm} \\ 
   & Lentes & \Block{1-2}{Sistema de escaneo de alta precisión\\2 dimensiones} \\ 
   & Velocidad de marcado & \Block{1-2}{$<8000$ mm/s} \\ 
   & \Block{2-1}{\textbf{Sistema de control principal}} & \Block{1-2}{Pantalla* integrada} \\ 
   &  & \Block{1-2}{Controlador táctil externo $10.4''$} \\ 
   & Sistema de enfriamiento & \Block{1-2}{Sistema de enfriamiento\\mediante agua o aire} \\ 
  %------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \Block{8-1}{Parámetros\\de marcado\\láser} 
   & \Block{1-1}{Aumento de enfoque\\ lentes (zoom)} & \Block{1-2}{$190$ mm en doble enfoque con luz roja} \\ 
   & Tipo de fuente de marcado &  \Block{1-2}{Marcado elegible entre gráficos vectoriales\\o mapas de bits} \\ 
   & Ancho de línea mínimo & \Block{1-2}{$0.012$ mm} \\ 
   & Precisión de repetibilidad & \Block{1-2}{$0.003$ mm} \\ 
   & Área de trabajo & \Block{1-2}{$110$ mm $\times$ $110$ mm} \\ 
   & Posicionamiento & \Block{1-2}{Luz roja posiciona, doble luz roja enfoca} \\ 
   & Línea de marcado & \Block{1-2}{Sin límite el área de trabajo} \\ 
   & Velocidad & \Block{1-2}{$0$-$200$ m/min} \\ 
  %-----------------------------------------------------------------
  \Block{2-1}{Otros} & Suministro de energía & \Block{1-2}{$220$ V} \\ 
   & Consumo de potencia & \Block{1-2}{$600$ W} 
\CodeAfter
  \tikz
  \draw [line width = 1.2pt]
    (1-|1) rectangle (22-|5) 
    (2-|1)  -- (2-|5) 
    (3-|1)  -- (3-|5) 
    (12-|1) -- (12-|5) 
    (20-|1) -- (20-|5) 
    (3-|2)  -- (22-|2) 
    (2-|3)  -- (22-|3) ;
\end{NiceTabular} 

\end{table}

\end{document}
```

You need two compilations (because informations, in particular for PGF/Tikz nodes, will be written on the `aux` file after the first compilation).

[image: Output of the above code]

Comment: You should specify that your solution requires a double compilation.

Comment: @AndréC: You are right. I will add  a remark.

Comment: Thanks for your help @F.Pantigny I've tried your code, it is very cool :D
I am newbie in nice tabular, sorry to ask you this but, how I can make the width of columns "Modelo 1" and "Modelo 2" have the same width?

I compiled first in LuaLaTex and after Quick Build in TeX Maker, is that what you meant @AndréC?

Comment: @user221144 Double compilation means that you have to `run twice` pdfLaTeX (or LaTeX or another engine)  in succession before viewing the result.

Comment: @user221144: You can put `\makebox[3.5cm][c]{\textbf{Modelo1}} ` in the cell for `Modelo1` (and `\makebox[3.5cm][c]{\textbf{Modelo2}}` in the cell for `Modelo2` --- instead of the low-level TeX code I have written first...).

Comment: @user221144: I have modified the code in my answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot @F.Pantigny you helped me so much!

Comment: @F.Pantigny I saw you are the author of this extension, you are awesome! I have another question (sorry). I can compile your answer perfectly in TeX Maker (and MikTex) in Windows 10, but when I tried in Overleaf I could compile but only appered the text, not the table neither colour. And in Ubuntu 18.04 (using Tex Maker and TeX live full) I can't compile at all. Do you have any clue? Thanks for your attention.

Comment: @user221144: In Overleaf, you have to upload the file `nicematrix.sty` corresponding to the latest version of `nicematrix` in your Overleaf project (on CTAN, there is only the file `nicematrix.dtx` but the `README` file recalls the technic to extract the `sty`). As for Ubuntu, I think that the LaTeX versions in the packets Ubuntu 2018 are too old. We have to install TeXLive 2020 via Vanilla TeX and update the installation to use the latest version of `nicematrix`.

Comment: Thank you @F.Pantigny!!! :D

Answer (score 1):

With use of the `tabularx` package and accordingly defined `\multicolumn` cells:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}

\usepackage[table,svgnames,x11names]{xcolor}
\usepackage{hhline}
\usepackage{makecell, multirow, tabularx}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}

\usepackage{siunitx} % new

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[ht]
    \newcommand\hlx {\hhline{|>{\arrayrulecolor{LightSteelBlue}}->{\arrayrulecolor{black}}|-|-|-|}}
    \newcommand\hlxx{\hhline{|>{\arrayrulecolor{LightSteelBlue}}-->{\arrayrulecolor{black}}|-|-|}}
    \newcommand\mcxx[1]{\multicolumn{2}
                    {>{\hsize=\dimexpr 1.6\hsize+2\tabcolsep+1.2pt}C!{\vrule width1.2pt}} % \hsize=\textwidth/4
                    {\cellcolor{Gainsboro}{#1}}}
    \renewcommand\arraystretch{1.1}
    \renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[1]{m{#1}}
    \small
    \centering
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}
               {!{\vrule width1.2pt}>{\columncolor{LightSteelBlue}\hsize=0.8\hsize}X
                !{\vrule width1.2pt}>{\columncolor{Gainsboro}\bfseries\hsize=1.6\hsize}L
                !{\vrule width1.2pt}>{\columncolor{Gainsboro}\hsize=0.8\hsize}C
                !{\vrule width1.2pt}>{\columncolor{Gainsboro}\hsize=0.8\hsize}C!{\vrule width1.2pt}
               }
    \Xhline{1.2pt}
\multicolumn{4}{c}{\textsc{Características y parámetros \dots}}    \\
    \Xhline{1pt} 
    \rowcolor{LightSteelBlue}
\multicolumn{2}{!{\vrule width1.2pt} c !{\vrule width1.2pt}}{}                              
    & \multicolumn{2}{c!{\vrule width1.2pt}}{\textbf{Modelo}}       \\
    \hlxx
    \rowcolor{LightSteelBlue}
\multicolumn{2}{!{\vrule width1.2pt}
                >{\hsize=\dimexpr 2.4\hsize+2\tabcolsep+1.2pt}X
                !{\vrule width1.2pt}
                }
               {\multirow{-2}{=}{\centering\textbf{item}}}
            &   \textbf{1}  &   \textbf{1}                              \\
    \Xhline{1pt}
    &   Material de máquina
        &   \mcxx{Estructuras de aluminio}                              \\
    \hlx
    & Láser 
        &   \mcxx{Generador de láser: Fibra óptica}                     \\
    \hlx
    &   Potencia de salida
        &   \cellcolor{Azure3}{$\geq 20W$}
            &   \cellcolor{Azure3}{$\geq 30W$}                          \\
    \hlx
    & Longitud de onda          & \mcxx{\SI{1064}{nm}}                  \\
    \hlx
    & Lentes                    & \mcxx{Sistema de escaneo de 
                                        alta precisión 2 dimensiones}   \\
    \hlx
    & Lentes                    & \mcxx{Sistema de escaneo de
                                        alta precisión 2 dimensiones}   \\
    \hlx
    & Velocidad de marcado      & \mcxx{\SI{<8000}{mm/s}}               \\
    \hlx
    & Sistema de control principal
                                & \mcxx{Controlador táctil externo \SI{10.4}{''} 
                                        Pantalla* integrada}            \\
    \hlx
\multirow{-12}{=}{Características máquina láser}
    & Sistema de enfriamiento   & \mcxx{Sistema de enfriamiento
                                        mediante agua o aire}           \\
%------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \Xhline{1pt} 
    & Aumento de enfoque lentes (zoom)        
                                & \mcxx{\SI{190}{mm} en doble
                                        enfoque con luz roja}           \\
    \hlx
    & Tipo de fuente de marcado & \mcxx{Marcado elegible entre gráficos
                                        vectoriales o mapas de bits}    \\
    \hlx
    & Ancho de línea mínimo     & \mcxx{\SI{0.012}{mm}}                 \\
    \hlx
    & Precisión de repetibilidad& \mcxx{\SI{0.003}{mm}}                 \\
    \hlx
    & Área de trabajo           & \mcxx{\SI{110x110}{mm}}               \\
    \hlx
    & Posicionamiento           & \mcxx{Luz roja posiciona,
                                        doble luz roja enfoca}          \\
    \hlx
    & Línea de marcado          & \mcxx{Sin límite el área de trabajo}  \\
    \hlx
\multirow{-9}{=}{Parámetros de marcado láser}
    & Velocidad                 & \mcxx{\SIrange{0}{200}{m/min}}        \\
%-----------------------------------------------------------------
    \Xhline{1pt}
    & Suministro de energía     & \mcxx{\SI{220}{V}}                    \\
    \hlx
\multirow{-2}{=}{Otros} 
    &   Consumo de potencia     & \mcxx{\SI{600}{W}}                    \\
    \Xhline{1.2pt}
\end{tabularx}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer width hhline! Also, I've learned of siunitx package for you. Great, @Zarko!

Answer (score 1):

It is known that `makecell` has problems with table colouring, because there are nested tabulars with their own `\tabcolsep`s behind the scene. So I used `\Centerstack` from `stackengine`. Further, to ensure the last two columns have equal width, I defined them as `X` columns and used a `tabularx` environment. Also used `boldline` for thick vertical lines for its simpler syntax, and simplified the use of `\hhline`:

```
    \documentclass[10pt, a4paper]{report}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage[spanish,es-noshorthands]{babel} %es-noshorthands sirve para que el cambio de color en hhline sea efectivo
    \usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
    \usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
    \usepackage[table,svgnames,x11names]{xcolor}
    \usepackage{hhline}
    \usepackage{boldline}
    \usepackage{multirow,makecell,array}
    \usepackage{diagbox}
    \usepackage{tabularx}
    \usepackage{tabulary}
    \usepackage{adjustbox}
    \usepackage[column= O]{cellspace}
    \setlength{\cellspacetoplimit}{3pt}
    \setlength{\cellspacebottomlimit}{3pt}
    \addparagraphcolumntypes{X}
    \usepackage{anyfontsize}
    \usepackage[usestackEOL]{stackengine}
    \usepackage{siunitx}

    \begin{document}
    \newcolumntype{g}{>{\columncolor{LightSteelBlue}}c}
    \newcolumntype{h}{>{\columncolor{Gainsboro}}Oc}
    \newcolumntype{k}{>{\columncolor{Azure3}\centering\arraybackslash}X}

    \begin{table}
    \scriptsize
    \centering
    \setlength{\extrarowheight}{2pt}
    \sisetup{range-phrase=--, range-units=single}
    \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{V{3}g V{3}h V{3}kV{3}k V{3}}%
    \Xhline{1.2pt}
    \multicolumn{4}{V{3}OcV{3}}{{\textsc{Características y parámetros...}}} \\
    \Xhline{1.2pt}
    \multicolumn{2}{V{3}gV{3}}{\diagbox[innerwidth=6cm, linewidth=1.2pt]{\textbf{Ítem}}{\textbf{Modelo}}} & \textbf{Modelo1} & \textbf{Modelo2} \\
    \Xhline{1.2pt} %
     & \textbf{Material de máquina} & \multicolumn{2}{hV{3}}{Estructuras de aluminio} \\[-0.5pt]
    \hhline{~---}
     & \textbf{Láser} & \multicolumn{2}{hV{3}}{Generador de láser: Fibra óptica} \\[-0.45pt]
    \hhline{~---}
     & \textbf{Potencia de salida} & $\geq \SI{20}{W}$ & $\geq \SI{30}{W}$ \\[-0.5pt]
    \hhline{~---}
     & \textbf{Longitud de onda} & \multicolumn{2}{hV{3}}{\SI{1064}{\nm}} \\[-0.5pt]
    \hhline{~---}
     & \textbf{Lentes} & \multicolumn{2}{hV{3}}{\Centerstack{Sistema de escaneo de alta precisión\\2 dimensiones}} \\[-0.5pt]
    \hhline{~---}
     & \textbf{Velocidad de marcado} & \multicolumn{2}{hV{3}}{$<\SI{8000}{\mm\per s}$} \\[-0.5pt]
    \hhline{~---}
     & \textbf{Sistema de control principal} & \multicolumn{2}{hV{3}}{\Centerstack{Pantalla* integrada \\ Controlador táctil externo 10.4''}} \\[-0.5pt]
    \hhline{~---}
    \multirowcell{-11}{Características\\máquina láser} & \textbf{Sistema de enfriamiento} & \multicolumn{2}{hV{3}}{%
    \Centerstack{Sistema de enfriamiento\\mediante agua o aire}} \\
    %------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \Xhline{1.2pt}
     & \Centerstack{\textbf{Aumento de enfoque}\\ \textbf{lentes (zoom)}} & \multicolumn{2}{hV{3}}{190\,mm en doble enfoque con luz roja} \\[-0.5pt]
    \hhline{~---}
     & \textbf{Tipo de fuente de marcado} & \multicolumn{2}{hV{3}}{\Centerstack{Marcado elegible entre gráficos vectoriales\\o mapas de bits}} \\[-0.5pt]
    \hhline{~---}
     & \textbf{Ancho de línea mínimo} & \multicolumn{2}{hV{3}}{0.012\,mm} \\[-0.5pt]
    \hhline{~---}
     & \textbf{Precisión de repetibilidad} & \multicolumn{2}{hV{3}}{0.003\,mm} \\[-0.45pt]
    \hhline{~---}
     & \textbf{Área de trabajo} & \multicolumn{2}{hV{3}}{$\SI{110}{mm} × \SI{110}{mm}$} \\[-0.5pt]
    \hhline{~---}
     & \textbf{Posicionamiento} & \multicolumn{2}{hV{3}}{Luz roja posiciona, doble luz roja enfoca} \\[-0.5pt]
    \hhline{~---}
     & \textbf{Línea de marcado} & \multicolumn{2}{hV{3}}{Sin límite el área de trabajo} \\[-0.5pt]
    \hhline{~---}
    \multirow{-10}{*}[2ex]{\Centerstack{Parámetros\\de marcado\\láser}} & \textbf{Velocidad} & \multicolumn{2}{hV{3}}{\SIrange{0}{200}{m/min}} \\
    %-----------------------------------------------------------------
    \Xhline{1.2pt}
     & \textbf{Suministro de energía} & \multicolumn{2}{hV{3}}{220\,V} \\[-0.45pt]
    \hhline{~---}
    \multirow{-2}{*}{Otros} & \textbf{Consumo de potencia} & \multicolumn{2}{hV{3}}{ 600\,W } \\
    \Xhline{1.2pt}
    \end{tabularx}
    \end{table}

    \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer width hhline! Also, I've learned of siunitx package for you. Great, @Bernard!